# jQuery checkbox always returns 'undefined'

Tags: jquery

Info: jQuery 1.6.0
HTML checkbox:

First I've made sure jQuery is loaded with:

```
if(jQuery) {
    alert("loaded");
}
```

And this is the case, it's loaded.
Then immidiately the line after that I use:

```
var returnvalue = jQuery("#mycheckbox").attr("checked");
alert(returnvalue);
```

This, for some reason, always alerts 'undefined'. I'm 100% sure the ID exists. I've also tried the following method:

```
jQuery("#mycheckbox").find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    alert("foo");
    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) 
        ReturnVal = true;
});
```

But this doesn't even pop up the alert.

What am I doing wrong? I'm by far a jQuery or Javascript expert, but this should work... right?

Edit:
I've tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert(id);
    var returnvalue = jQuery("#" . id).prop("checked");
    alert(returnvalue);
});
```

The alert(id) gives me the proper ID, but alert(returnvalue) returns undefined.

I've also tried:

```
if(jQuery) { 
    alert("loaded");
} 
jQuery(function() {
    alert(id);
    var returnvalue = jQuery("#" . id).attr("checked");
    alert(returnvalue);
});
```

Same result

Edit2:
After using .prop AND appending the id with a '+' instead of a '.' (PHP habit), it works. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: `jQuery("#" . id)` is just wrong. You're asking for the `id` property of the `"#"` string.

Comment: Damn, you're right! This is my first time working with javascript, I've always worked with PHP, so I'm used to the '.'. You're totally right, this even fixed my problem, thank you incredibly much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- If you're using jQuery `1.6` or later, use `prop()` instead of `attr()`:

```
var returnvalue = jQuery("#mycheckbox").prop("checked");
```

This is because if you didn't include an explicit `checked` attribute with the element, then the attribute is `undefined` though the property will have its default.

---

- You need to eliminate the `.find()`:

```
jQuery("#mycheckbox").each(function(){
    alert("foo");
    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) 
        ReturnVal = true;
});
```

---

Including your HTML in the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if(jQuery) {
    alert("loaded");
}
$(function() {
    var returnvalue = $("#mycheckbox").attr("checked");
    alert(returnvalue);
});
```

**Update**

If your script is at the top of the page, it executes before the HTML is loaded. During that time, attr('checked') is undefined.

By wrapping the code in a self-executing anonymous function $(function(){...}), your code executes after the HTML loads.

**Answer to comment**

Your code:

```
function isChecked(id)
{
    if(jQuery) { alert("loaded"); } 
    $(function() {
        alert(id);
        var returnvalue = $("#" + id).attr("checked"); 
        alert(returnvalue); 
    });
}
```

Try this. what does it alert?

```
function isChecked(id)
{
    if(jQuery) { alert("loaded"); } 
    alert(id);
    alert('there are this many elements with matching id: ' + $("#" . id).length);
    var returnvalue = $("#" + id).attr("checked"); 
    alert(returnvalue); 
}
```

Does the 3rd alert say "there are this many elements with matching id: 0"?

Comment: I now have the following code:
`function isChecked(id){
    if(jQuery) {
        alert("loaded");
    }
    $(function() {
        alert(id);
        var returnvalue = $("#" . id).attr("checked");
        alert(returnvalue);
    });`

which still returns undefined. The alert(id) alerts the proper ID. Furthermore, when I press submit (the page is loaded already then ofcourse), it still returns undefined.

Comment: please post code updates in your original question, they are hard to read in comments.

Comment: Hi, it alerts 'there are this many elements with matching id: 0'.

Comment: Then the problem is that the script is executing while there is no HTML element with id="id_of_element". Try moving the script to the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag. If it still says zero elements, you will need to post your HTML.

Comment: Seems like we both made the same mistake, we're using a '.' instead of a '+' to append. It works now! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `.prop` `$('#checkbox1').prop('checked')`, jQuery 1.6 +

Concerning boolean attributes, consider a DOM element defined by the HTML markup `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`, and assume it is in a JavaScript variable named elem:

```
elem.checked    true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
$(elem).prop("checked") true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
elem.getAttribute("checked")    "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6)    "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6.1+) "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state
$(elem).attr("checked")(pre-1.6)    true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state
```

According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute has no value or an empty string value. The preferred cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to check for a "truthy" value on the element's property using one of the following:

```
if ( elem.checked )
if ( $(elem).prop("checked") )
if ( $(elem).is(":checked") )
```

If using jQuery 1.6, the code `if ( $(elem).attr("checked") )` will retrieve the actual content attribute, which does not change as the checkbox is checked and unchecked. It is meant only to store the default or initial value of the checked property. To maintain backwards compatability, the `.attr()` method in jQuery 1.6.1+ will retrieve and update the property for you so no code for boolean attributes is required to be changed to .prop(). Nevertheless, the preferred way to retrieve a checked value is with one of the options listed above. To see how this works in the latest jQuery, check/uncheck the checkbox in the example below.